# Unity sometimes loading a scene twice while using Async loading

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a "Persistent Scene" which is always in the background which handles loading and unloading through a GameManager script. How this script is activated is by entering a trigger and pressing "E" which will load another scene.

**Example of loading into a forest**

Script which is on the trigger:

```
public class ForestEnter : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        
        
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
           GameManager.instance.LoadForest();
        }
    }
}
```

Part of the script which is in the GameManger:

```
        public void LoadForest()
    {
        scenesLoading.Add(SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync((int)SceneIndexes.CITY));
        scenesLoading.Add(SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync((int)SceneIndexes.FOREST, LoadSceneMode.Additive));
        spawnname = ("CityExit");
        sceneName = ("Forest");
        StartCoroutine(GetSceneLoadProgress());

    }
```

And the Coroutine it's calling (to make sure it waits until everything's loaded before finding the spawn and setting the scene as the "Active Scene")

```
    public IEnumerator GetSceneLoadProgress()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<scenesLoading.Count; i++)
        {
            while (!scenesLoading[i].isDone)
            {
                yield return null;
            }
        }
        player = GameObject.Find("PC");
        playerPOS = player.transform;
        spawn = GameObject.Find(spawnname);
        spawnPOS = spawn.transform;
        playerPOS.position = spawnPOS.position;
        SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName(sceneName));
        
    }
```

Now my problem is that sometimes it will load the scene twice, as in there will be a total of 3 scenes playing, the GameManager scene, Forest scene, and Forest scene again. It only happens sometimes though, not every time.

I assume the problem is that if I'm holding down "E" too long it'll call the script as many times as it can before it gets unloaded, but I don't know how I would go about stopping that.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @HassanOmar said, the issue is you are triggering the load multiple times.  This is because you're checking *every frame* the key is pressed, but you really only want the *first* frame the key is pressed.  You do this with `Input.GetKeyDown()`:

```
public class ForestEnter : MonoBehaviour
{    
    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {        
    
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            GameManager.instance.LoadForest();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This due to multiple calling of **OnTriggerStay2D** just you can use boolean variable to avoid this

```
  public class ForestEnter : MonoBehaviour
  {
         public bool flag = true;
    
         void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
         {
        
        
             if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && flag)
             { 
                 GameManager.instance.LoadForest();
                 flag  =false; 
             }
         }
     }
```

> ***This Only if you need it*** 
> Also you can Reset this flag at start function at any script in new scene
> or reset at end of operation that load next scene
> here is line to do it

```
FindObjectOfType<ForestEnter>().flag = true;
```

Comment: Your understanding of the error is correct, but your solution is... suboptimal.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help out, but Immersive's way of doing it is a lot more simple.

Comment: Never mind I know Immersive's Solution is optimal but If You Don't have to check if E key is pressed "for example designed this product for mobiles " You will use my solution

Comment: Well, no, because even on Mobile you are probably going to be using either the ```Input``` system, or a UI ```Button``` which has its own trigger-once feature.  Your answer is good when there's no readily available "state change" metric available, but that is rarely the case for user input middleware.